# how to transfer files with reverse proxy ftp in winscp

Tags: winscp

I have set up reverse proxy ftp..

I just want to transfer files from windows to ftp server via reverse proxy server in winscp.

How can we access reverse proxy ftp url in winscp for transferring files.

Comment: Hi I have read the link which is given above.. but if i am selecting proxy type as http in proxy page, it is asking for proxy name.lets say if i am having proxy name as testdrive.cn. my ftp request over http is is http://testdrive.cn/ftp ..how to enter the same. kindly clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse proxy server should be transparent to the client.

Just use an IP address of the proxy as FTP server Host name in WinSCP.

Comment: hi, If i am adding IP address of the proxy server  in hostname field. Since the reverse proxy server is having only 80 and 443 ports opened, i cant select FTP as file protocol.

Comment: Then it does not look like the reverse proxy allows you to use the FTP protocol.

Comment: I have made configuration in such a way that if i am accessing https://testdrive.cn/ftp where testdrive.cn is the reverse proxy host name and if i give /ftp in that url it will access the FTP server via reverse proxy  and i am able to see the files which is available in FTP server..But i want to transfer files to that ftp server via reverse proxy server. so i thought of achieving it with winscp

Comment: First that information should be in your question from the very first moment! + That does not have anything to with with FTP anyway. There are no URLs in FTP. That's probably just an HTTP/HTML page rendered from FTP data. You cannot "connect" to that with FTP client.

Comment: do you mean to say we cannot achieve it with reverse proxy. in Winscp i have given port as 443 and host name as reverse proxy server ip . since port 443 is given , file protocol changed automatically to webDav. Next i have clicked on advanced settings ->proxy and in the protocol type , i have selected http and proxy name as testdrive.cn with the port 80. but how do i mention testdrive.cn/ftp in the proxy name?somehow i need to tell winscp like it has to connect to ftp server via reverse proxy server. Is that possible?

Comment: Martin Please clarify me one more thing also.even if i am opening port 21 in reverse proxy server, Is it possible to achieve transfer files to ftp server with reverse proxy server using port 21?kindly confirm this.

Comment: No I mean you cannot connect using the reverse proxy with the given configuration (ports 80 and 443 only). It should work, if you open port 21 and all data connection ports.

Comment: ok Thanks Martin.one last question to ask.. Lets say i am opening port 21 in reverse proxy server. lets have reverse proxy server as A and FTP Server as B. So after opening port 21 in server A.if i am connecting to server A(reverse proxy server) with port 21  will connect me to FTP server? and it will cause the file which i am transferring to go to FTP server? kindly confirm this alone. do i need to mention anything in advanced options ->proxy in winscp in order to achieve this.

Comment: 1) Yes - but to transfer files, you need to open data connections ports too + 2) No - reverse proxy server is transparent to the client -  I've already mentioned this in my answer

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answers.. I am able to see only port 21 as data connection port. Apart from that , do we have any other data connection port?

Comment: 21 is **not** data connection port. It's control connection port. What data connection ports your FTP server use, depends on its configuration.

Comment: You are welcome. Though on Super User, we thank by [accepting the answer](//superuser.com/help/someone-answers).